# Best way to have group-wide/global CI on gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In our organization, we host a simple GitLab server.

For one group (that serves as some kind of data collection), I want to have the same CI pipelines for all repositories.

Is there a way to define CI pipelines for a group (or alternatively system-wide)?

Answer (score 0):

#### By GitLab pipelines.

You have to put `.gitlab-ci.yml` for all projects.

And inside `.gitlab-ci.yml` include any link to the file. It could be a dynamically generated yml file by service.

```
include:
  - 'https://s3.domain/gitlab-ci.yml'
```

No way to strictly create or have repositories without the required pipeline. However, You can periodically scan all repositories by service and notify if your violator does not add the necessary include.

#### The dirty solution.

You can enable [instance level or group level integration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/project_integration_management.html#manage-instance-level-default-settings-for-a-project-integration) with another CI. And forcefully set up a pipeline for every project without push to Gitlab.